# Can someone please confirm the reason behind foreach loop giving error as "invalid token" and "splittedText" as does not exist in current context?

Tags: c#, file, foreach

```
    string[] splittedText = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt");//.Split(',');

    foreach (string data in splittedText)
    {
    }
```

I want to read through a file in c# which returns array of string type. Then, I will be iterating over the array to fetch my desired data.

Comment: The Split belongs here: `foreach (string data in splittedText.Split(','))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a CSV file, you should use a CVS parser. Values in the CSV file are separated using command and in some cases, the value in the CSV file can also contain a comma. In that case, the column values are wrapped in double-quotes. And this solution will not handle that scenario.

```
var splittedText = File.ReadAllText("E:\\Test.txt").Split(',');

foreach (string data in splittedText)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint - Reading file line by line or Reading whole file content depends on your use case. May be below code snippet give some idea on how to split the content.
Please try.

```
var inputtext = File.ReadAllText(@"inpufile.txt");

inputtext.Replace("\n", "")
.Split(',',
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
.ToList().ForEach(t =>
 {
  System.Console.WriteLine(t);
  //Other manupulations
  });
```

if you want to split based on multiple characters , pass a character array to the split().

```
new char[] { ',', ':' };
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You need change File.ReadAllLines to File.ReadAllText(path) then you can split method.